# call_user_func() or $callback() not working

Tags: php, function, callback

In a PHP routing file, I want to make a callback to a function called `homepage_display()`.

The function name is in the `$callback` variable, and when I make the call, it doesn't work:

```
$callback = "homepage_display";

$callback(); // doesn't work
call_user_func($callback); // doesn't work either
homepage_display(); // works!!
```

Whereas this specific piece of code just above works in any snippet, the same mechanism doesn't work in one of my functions. Any idea of what can cause such a behavior? I tried removing the `_` thinking it might be an encoding problem, but it doesn't solve anything.

**EDIT:**

To make my point absolutely clear, I added an explicit assignation `$callback="homepage_display";`, just before calling it as a callback function. You can see on this picture that it just does not work. Whereas calling `homepage_display();` directly, does. If somebody understands something, I'm curious :)

**Not working:**
[image: Not working]

**Working:**
[image: Working]

Comment: Works fine for me: http://3v4l.org/GuNUN

Comment: Yeah, works fine for me too, but not with the actual route() function. And I checked (trying to print $callback just before using it as a callback function), everything seems ok. Except it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, in one word: `namespace foo\bar;`.

One cannot call `$callback();` when in the scope of a non-global namespace.

One has to call `call_user_func(__NAMESPACE__.'\\'.$callback);` instead.

It can get tricky sometimes ;)

Comment: That's an good point, I also stumbled over this problem and was irritated by the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here:

```
php > function foo() { echo 'foo!'; }
php > $bar = 'foo';
php > call_user_func($bar);
foo!
php > $bar();
foo!
```

Did you verify that your `testRoute()` actually returns `true`? If it doesn't, then your "autoloader" will never get called.

Comment: @Marc B: yes because in the conditional statement, if I replace $callback() with homepage_display(), then it works. And if I print $callback, it prints the string "homepage_display"... Strange behavior.

Comment: Love how you use quotes to say your "autoloader"